# What is difference between 熱を出す and 熱が出る

Tags: phrases, transitivity

I know that [**熱が出る (netsu ga deru)** means to have a fever](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E7%86%B1%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B).

Example:

> 風邪を引いたら、39℃の熱が出た。
>
> Kaze wo hiitara, 39C no netsu ga deta
>
> When I caught a cold, I had a fever of 39C.

**What does 熱を出す (netsu wo dasu) mean?**

These are the examples I have:

> 1. でも熱出して寂しいって言ってた。
>
> Demo netsu dashite sabishii tte itte ta
>
> 2. 彼女は体が弱いので、何かあるとすぐに熱を出す。
>
> Kanojo wa karada ga yowai no de, nanika aru to sugu ni netsu wo dasu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference relates to the more general difference between transitive and intransitive verbs, with transitive verbs being accompanied by an active agent which is a causal factor.

In your examples, the intransitive verb 出る is used to state a fact that the heat/fever is happening of its own accord, i.e. 熱が出た = I have a fever. By using the transitive verb 出す, there is more emphasis on the active agent. This is sometimes used when referring to things like chemical reactions, where the reaction 'gives off heat', i.e. there is something which is actively causing the release of heat. For example, [高い熱を出す性質](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E7%86%B1%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99) (the property of giving off heat). In your example,  体が弱いのですぐに熱を出す is emphasizing the causal factor of her weak constitution as being responsible for the fever. It's a subtle nuance, but with 熱が出る it's simply stating a fact and with 熱を出す it's pointing to the active agent which is causing the fever.

Comment: And in this context: でも 熱 出して 寂しい って 言ってた
Demo netsu deshite sabishii tte itte ta

Comment: There isn't enough context to interpret what exactly is meant by the phrase without knowing what came before it. But the use of 出す implies some kind of active causal factor to the fever.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the example.

> 私は骨を折った。 *I broke a bone.*
> 私は骨が折れた。 *A bone of mine broke.*

The former sounds like that the bone fracture as such is a remarkable event that happens to the person. The latter is more like mentioning it as a consequence of another event (like car accident) or something.

Similarly, 熱が出る is more like told as a part of a disease's symptom or that like, while 熱を出す is itself a life event. In English you usually only say "have/run a fever", but I might consider translating 熱が出る "fever develops" if I really need to disambiguate.